# Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 18.04, gdm

On Ubuntu 18.04, I have connected my laptop to an external display and I am able to set the external display as primary and external display only mode. But when I turn on my laptop or log out from my session the display login screen is displayed only on my(internal) laptop screen. But once I login the display switches to external only and my laptop screen turns off as expected.

Is there a way I can make the login screen appear only on the external screen on bootup or on logout as in 16.04? Also the login screen does not follow my cursor as in 16.04.

Comment: To anyone affected by this bug: please comment on or upvote the [upstream bug report against GDM3](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/issues/372), so that the developers know this issue is important

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This Solved my Isuue:

Go into Settings > Devices > Displays and configure your monitors the way you want for your login screen (in your case, internal laptop display disabled). Click the "Save" button when done.

Copy your user's `monitors.xml` file into the home folder for `gdm` user.

To copy the monitors.xml file, open a terminal and perform the following:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

**And in the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` uncomment
 WaylandEnable=false**

Comment: How is this answer different from Damian T.'s answer?

Comment: This is the only answer that made the login screen appear on my external monitor. However, when I actually logged in, I only got a black screen and had to recovery-mode to undo the `WaylandEndable=false`.

Comment: It worked for me. I tried the other answers and they didn't work, but this one works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS!!! you will loose ability to login (blank screen and kick back to login) until you undo changes in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 20.04) that really helped. I had to uncomment WaylandEnable=false.

Comment: Tried this method a dozen and still can't get the login screen to show up on the right monitor. On Ubuntu 21.04 btw

Comment: @TechEmperor95, had the same trouble and found out that you have to configure monitors specifically in x11 session before coping monitors.xml - Waylang and X-server has different settings

Comment: Perfect answer for 22.04.  Worked exactly as expected (and I didn't lose the ability to login or get a blank screen).  Try CTRL+ALT+F2 or any other function key to get to a login prompt.  CTRL+ALT+F1 goes back to the graphical desktop/login screen.

Answer (score 105):

This is a known and [reported bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3867) with **gdm3**.  The current workaround appears to be:

1. Go into `Settings > Devices > Displays` and configure your monitors the way you want for your login screen (in your case, internal laptop display disabled).  Click the "Save" button when done.
   (**Note:** Changing this setting with an alternate desktop environment—such as Cinnamon—may not propagate the intended change.)
2. Copy your user's `monitors.xml` file into the home folder for `gdm` user.

To copy the `monitors.xml` file, open a terminal and perform the following:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

Then, reboot and see if your changes persist.  If this doesn't work, try going through the whole process again.  It took me two times in order to get it to stick.  I was also able to reboot with my external display disconnected and it switched back to my internal laptop display.  I rebooted again and reconnected it and it switches back to my external monitor.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. For some reason it’s not sticking to the external display on boot up, tried about 4 times. Will wait for the bug to be resolved.

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: To me the terminal statements were enough to fix the issue. This means that I didn't executed the second part from the Aravind answer. Thanks Damian. Still I don't get WHY this isn't resolved by Ubuntu itself after so many years.

Comment: Thank you. It is 2020 and this bug is still not fixed. Why??

Comment: +1 Thank you - with Ubuntu 20.04 I found this solution to work. This and the currently accepted answer ( https://askubuntu.com/a/1048966/7072 ) are almost the same steps. In my situation I have three monitors, one of them is connected via a StarTech USB3 to HDMI running with DisplayLink driver. Initially the screen I wanted for login was the case but strangely for a reason I don't know, the login was displayed on one of the other screens. Doing your solution appears to have fixed the issue in my case. I rebooted and the screen I wanted the login to appear is still as required.

Comment: I did not have to do "And in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncomment WaylandEnable=false" in the currently accepted answer.

Comment: This works with Ubuntu 20.04. In my case I have two screens. I swapped the screens between left and right as a better fit for my need because the connectors and the size are not the same. It works fine with my session, but not on the login screen. The screens were still swapped to the default. I managed to fix it with your method.  Thank you very much.

Comment: This solution worked on my Ubuntu 20.04 computer, with 3 DisplayPort screens.

Comment: Those two lines work perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04. Repeating the procedure was not necessary.

Comment: Those two lines work perfectly on Ubuntu 23.10. Repeating the procedure was not necessary.

Answer (score 37):

I too have an external monitor. This worked for me:

- Set your display mode as desired using **Settings** > **Devices** > **Displays**
- Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and then type:

  `sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config`
- Hit **Enter**
- Reboot the computer

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me on Ubuntu 18... this folder actually exists unlike `/home/gdm`

Comment: /var/lib/gdm3 is ~gdm , its gdm's home directory.  Services user accounts don't usually get home directories in /home .

Comment: cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/gdm/.config': No such file or directory; 
cp: cannot create regular file '/var/lib/gdm3/.config': No such file or directory; 
cp: cannot create regular file '~gdm/.config': No such file or directory; 

Great. Where has the folder moved in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS? Does it matter I'm using Gnome 3.28.2 and Wayland?

Comment: This solution worked for me, the accepted one did not. Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome-flashback. My display configuration now even works with a multi-computer KVM switch.

Comment: Worked for **Ubuntu 20.04 Focal**.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the correct path to gdm3 home. Using "~gdm" does not get me anywhere (at least not on Debian Buster).

Comment: Note that `~gdm` != `~/gdm`

Comment: Worked for Ubuntu 21.04!

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 22.10 using an RX 6800 GPU with 2 outputs (DisplayPort = LG Monitor, HDMI = Samsung TV). Ubuntu was always starting with a black screen because the logon screen was using the TV as output (which was off). Now It boots using my PC monitor.