# How to make login screen display on second Monitor

Tags: login, screen

I need to change login screen to be shown on second Monitor

Comment: In my environment, the login screen follows my mouse pointer.  When you move your mouse does it appear on the same screen with your mouse?

Comment: No,  It does not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 login screen Display settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-display-settings)

Comment: Look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-display-settings

Comment: Refer here for latest solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/1082234/305000