# Switch from Dual Monitor Display to Single Display Permanently

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, laptop, lightdm

ISSUE: My laptop's display is broken, so i removed the in-built monitor (LVDS1-1) and bought an external monitor (HDMI-1-1).
Under Setting, I am able to change display mode to 'Single Display' as my HDMI-1-1. However, this setting kicks in only after I log in.

Before login, ubuntu treats it as dual monitor system and all the text is 'displayed' on LVDS-1-1 (which i can not see, since there is no monitor connected) (I am able to login by entering the password, but it is annoying)

QUESTION: How can I change the display mode to always be as Single Display, even before login?

ENVIRONMENT: 
-Ubuntu 18.04
-Nvidia GFX (Switchable mode with Intel)
-New to Linux

THINGS I TRIED:
1. Editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf (added active-monitor=0)
2. NVIDIA X Server Settings (Prime Displays cannot be controlled by nvidia-settings)
3. Editing ~/.config/monitors.xml (LVDS-1-1 is already disabled)

Comment: Have you tried setting the display mode to mirror? Might show everything on both screens until you find a good perm fix.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Yes. It works only after logging in. But before that, it is the same case as single display.
Strangely enough, in either case, I do see Ubuntu loading screen on HDMI-1-1 (the 5 dots screen)

Answer (score 2):

Partial Workable Solution:
Original: https://askubuntu.com/a/1048966/930126

```
1. sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config
2. in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf uncomment WaylandEnable=false
```

This does bring login screen to he external display.

The only (minor) issue that remains is that the initial startup screen with live logs (don't know what it is called) is still on the in-built display.

If anyone knows a better solution, that would be amazing. Otherwise this is sufficient for me, at the moment.