# Login screen appears on second monitor

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gdm, nvidia-geforce

After I choose Ubuntu from the GRUB menu which appears on the primary monitor, the **login screen** appears on the second monitor which is something that I don't want.

How can I prevent this, so that everything appears on the primary monitor?

[image: Nvida X Server Settings]

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/a/1082234/305000 for latest solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ubuntu 18.04 login screen Display settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-display-settings)

Copying the file `monitors.xml` from `/home/user/.config` into `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/` and

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```

In `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` changing from `#WaylandEnable = false` to `WaylandEnable = false` solved the issue.

---

**UPDATE**

The same things happen on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal Fossa, gdm somehow does not recognize which monitor is set as primary and the login screen appears on second Monitor.

Copying only monitors.xml solves the issue

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
```