# Settings with multiple monitors

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

How can I set the monitors throughout the entire system (and not just parts of it)?

My system consists of 3 monitors, one to the left, one in the middle, one to the right. The graphics card in use is an Nvidia GeForce 1050 Ti. After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I use the pre-installed application "Additional Drivers" which opens "Software & Updates" already set on the "Additional Drivers" tab. Then I installed the driver "NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-440 (proprietary, tested)".

When I start the system and reach the login, the actual login text field is on the right side monitor. After typing the password, the monitor settings reload to the right setting, having the middle monitor as the primary centered monitor. So at the login the right monitor is the primary monitor, and after login the middle monitor is the primary monitor. The display settings set inside the "Settings" application don't seem to apply outside of the desktop environment.

How can I set the monitors system wide and not just desktop wide?

Comment: you can simply follow this -- >https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153025/login-screen-appears-on-second-monitor/1154993#1154993