# How can I change the screen (graphics card) that the system uses when booting and disable the other one?

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, hdmi

I've got a triple boot system going on with Windows, Ubuntu and Mac. (It is a hackintosh).
I've got a problem, that is, my dedicated graphics card (Nvidia GTX 1660) isn't supported by Mac, so I wanted to boot Mac with the integrated graphics card of my processor (Intel i7 6700).

What I did is, as my screen has both a DVI input and a HDMI input, I plugged both a DVI to HDMI wire and a HDMI to HDMI wire to it, then one goes to the HDMI output of my dedicated card and the other one to the output of the motherboard (integrated one).

I have the Intel as the main card, but the system boots with both, in Mac it's not a problem since I have it configured so it doesn't recognize the Nvidia.

On the other hand, Windows thought I had 2 screens as it recognized both adapters, so I disabled the integrated card in it and now it uses the Nvidia card for everything (booting etc).

I have a problem when I boot Ubuntu though, it recognizes 2 screens, my screen loads the Nvidia Input (Screen 0 recognized by Ubuntu) but for some reason the login is on the other one (Screen 1). I've told it to just use Screen 1 in the settings, and it does when I have logged in, but outside of (at login) it it's still showing extended screens.

Is there a way I can force that setting accross all the system so it is like that when it boots and gets into the login too?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution here: [Ubuntu 18.04 login screen Display settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/ubuntu-18-04-login-screen-display-settings)

You have to change your settings as desired with your user logged in and then perform this two commands in the terminal:

`sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml`

`sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml`