# Ubuntu 20.04 login screen doesn't appear on the primary screen

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, login-screen, lock-screen

I don't understand why this important and many users concerned bug (easy to solve) exists since so many years and all the discussions refer to mark something as duplicate and outdated. This bug https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdm/-/issues/372 still exists in my fresh installation of ubuntu desktop 20.04 from yesterday. My tv is the primary screen, notebook via hdmi is open for powerbutton. Login screen appears unreadable for me on the build in notebook screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have fixed the problem with these line of code:

`sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml`

It only works if the desired monitor has been marked as primary first.

Comment: Note: A reboot after may be required for it to take effect

Comment: Hello from the future, currently using latest ubuntu 23.04. I tried this but it only works when you suspend. I also tried this with 22.04 as well as 22.10 both times same results. Do you know of anything else we can try to have monitor work after a reboot or power off?

Comment: @Blahblah, did you "chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml" like shown in the comment above? It works for me on 23.04. Btw I did not enable Xorg for gdm by disabling Wayland in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.

Answer (score 4):

I had to do some additional steps:

If you haven't done it yet, go to Settings → Devices → Displays and set your primary monitor. Save your settings.

Open a terminal and run the following:

```
sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
sudoedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

In the file uncomment `WaylandEnable=false`, and save.

Comment: I've those settings already, and I have the same problem :( ubuntu 20.04 . I have three monitors (just in case is relevant).

Comment: The two first commands can be merged into one with: 

`sudo install -m 0664 -o gdm -g gdm ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: It's neither working for me. Also on ubuntu 20.04LTS

Comment: Hello from the future, currently using latest ubuntu 23.04. I tried this but it only works when you suspend. I also tried this with 22.04 as well as 22.10 both times same results. Do you know of anything else we can try to have monitor work after a reboot or power off?

Comment: @Blahblah I did it right now, and at least for me, it worked, I'm using ubuntu 22.04, I didn't disabled Wayland, have you checked if the `<primary>` tag is set in the right display?