# How to control which monitor gdm3 login screen appears on?

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, gdm, nvidia-geforce

Ubuntu 22.04.4

I have five monitors connected to my computer, while facing them from left to right they are monitors 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

I would like the gdm login to appear on monitor #2.  I can't figure out how to do that, it always wants to appear on monitor #4.

In ~/.config/monitors.xml, I have the primary tag set only for monitor #2.

/var/lib/gdm3/.config/monitors.xml is an exact copy of ~/.config/monitors.xml, except that the ownership is "gdm".

I have followed these, but none helped, those solutions had no impact:

[Login screen on wrong monitor / display](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1432412/login-screen-on-wrong-monitor-display)

[Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04)

[Ubuntu 20.04 login screen doesn't appear on the primary screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1255230/ubuntu-20-04-login-screen-doesnt-appear-on-the-primary-screen)

In case this matters:

I have this for graphics: Intel Driver i915, model 4693; and NVIDIA model GK208B[GeForce GT 730]

I have the five monitors plugged into these two graphics cards: #2 and #3 are plugged into the Intel card with HDMI connectors. #1, #4, and #5 are plugged into the NVIDIA card: #1 with an HDMI connection, #4 with a VGA connection, and #5 with a DVI-D connection.  When I boot the computer, all the booting/bios messages scroll through on monitor #1 (but I'd like that to be on monitor #2), and the Ubuntu gdm login appears on monitor #4 instead of monitor #2.

How do I fix this?