# How to set correct displays setting at login screen before login (Ubuntu 20.04)?

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, display

I am currently using a dual-monitor display setup for my desktop. My left screen (DP-4) is configured as normal landscape and my primary screen, whereas my right screen (DP-0) is configured to rotate 90-degress for portrait viewing. The display settings are automatically setup correctly after I login. However, each time after I restart the computer AND before I login, I would have incorrect display configurations such that (1) my right screen (DP-0) becomes my primary screen instead to show the login information, and (2) my right screen information (DP-0) does not rotate 90-dgree (ie. leaving everything appearing vertical)

To provide more clear info on my setup, this would be the command I use for "xrandr" (please ignore DP-1, DP-2, DP-3, DP-5 as I am not using them as display output):

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 2560x1440 --pos 2560x0 --rotate right
       --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --off 
       --output DP-2 --off
       --output DP-3 --off
       --output DP-4 --primary --mode 2560x1440 --pos 0x560 --rotate normal
       --output DP-5 --off
```

I was able to save my permanent display settings by modifying `monitors.xml` at `/home/myname/.config/monitors.xml`. However, the display settings work automatically only AFTER I login.

I also added a simple shell script file at `/etc/profile.d` folder as I read somewhere that this could help. The bash script includes the `xrandr` command that I shared above. However, it did not change or help the situation.

Would appreciate so much if anyone can enlighten me on how to make the display settings at login screen (before logging in) to be same as post-login's display settings? This relatively silly issue really cause slight loss of joy of using Ubuntu every time I startup my computer, and thus just thanks much in advance for any help or advice:)

Comment: The use of ```sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml /var/lib/gdm3/.config```  resolved my issue perfectly as suggested by community member (many thanks!!) to review this link:)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04