# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly not working when started connected to external montiors

Tags: 20.04, startup, external-monitor

I'm using a Lenovo Thinkpad which came with Windows but I've wiped it and have used Ubuntu 20.04 for quite a while. After some initial issues getting everything to work with 3 external monitors via a docking station everything worked fine.

Today, when I cleaned up my cable setup a bit and stuck everything back in place (probably not every cable at the exact same place) it would not work when I started it.

I had previously followed this:

[Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04)

Which worked when using the accepted answer but now, no matter what I do seemingly, if I boot the laptop with the external monitors connected they all go black (including the built in display, which is usually fine since I have that disabled and the other 3 enabled).

Does anyone have any idea how this could be solved? The only work around I have currently is to start the computer with nothing connected and then connect everything after it has booted and logged in.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Start with  everything disconnected, then see if your monitor preferences makes an external monitor the primary one. Make your LCD screen on the Thinkpad your primary one if that's the case. If your docking station is a powered USB type, then you may want to make sure it is powered on before booting.

Do you use DisplayLink to manage your video setup?  You may want to remove and reinstall or fetch the latest Linux release from their website. I have found that DisplayLink using the same equipment has better support on a Mac than Linux, so maybe they are catching up.

Regards,
mondotofu

Comment: If I disconnect everything then the only monitor is the built in so its the primary one by default (it seems atleast). I use the dock to power the whole system on so its always on when the computer starts.

I don't use displaylink, should I perhaps?

Comment: If your docking station supports it, then you could download for free and see if that helps.  https://www.displaylink.com/