# How can I make my log-in screen appear on my external monitor only?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, login-screen

My setup currently consists of a laptop hooked up to an external monitor, and I would like for my log-in screen to display only on my external monitor when I boot up the computer as it would be faster and more practical. How can I go about doing this on Ubuntu 20.04? The other questions related to this issue seem to be focused on Ubuntu 18.04, and the answers they were given are non-applicable here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the laptop screen open when you use external monitor? Once login are you using both the screens?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop used `gdm3` same as 20.04 does, so why do you think *focal* is different?

Comment: yes the laptop screen is open when I use the external monitor, the log-in screen only displays on the internal monitor. @UnKNOWn

Comment: @guiverc, the other post says you need to go in Settings > Devices > Displays, however that tab is non-existent in the current gui.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04)

Comment: @UnKNOWn no, because like I said earlier, the recommendation in that post is to go to Settings > Devices > Displays. There is no Devices tab in the Settings app on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Can you search for displays settings?

Comment: There are no display settings with log-in screen options in the gui.