# Change default monitor on user selection screen

Tags: multiple-monitors

I primarily use an external monitor for my Ubuntu device, and I've configured it to display on only that monitor. However, while I'm on the user selection screen (before I've logged in), it displays it on the original monitor, instead of the external display.

How could I make Ubuntu use a different display while I'm in the user selection screen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Algnis I edited it and added a bit more details, let me know if there's any questions I could answer so you could help me better.

Comment: Yes, now it is looking great and direct!!! Keep it up!!!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1043337/1460940 Take a look at it, it seems to solve the issue

Comment: @Algnis I don't have anything in /home/gdm, should I create it?

Comment: Trying is always good but make sure you don't break your system

Comment: I'll try to reboot and see if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131619/discussion-between-ktibow-and-algnis).

Comment: That answered my question, yes. I flagged it as a duplicate of that.

Comment: But it is not marked as closed

Comment: You need to accept it on the above banner you are shown that does this answer your question

Comment: Alright, I did that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: :) ...............