# Second screen remains black after wake-up in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: asus, 22.04

I am using `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS` on `ASUS ZenBook Duo 14 (UX482)` laptop with dual screen.
Usually it works fine, but sometimes resuming after suspend it shows black screen for the second screen.

Only after reboot the second screen returns to working state.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Result of `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'`:

```
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: VGA
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [1043:1382]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Comment: Similar to [22.04 second monitor lost on login or wake](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404003/22-04-second-monitor-lost-on-login-or-wake) which has answers but none work for me.  Any luck for you yet?

Comment: Thank you for heading up, I'll check this solution.

Comment: Since then, I also found [How to get external monitor to reconnect after sleep or power off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333688/how-to-get-external-monitor-to-reconnect-after-sleep-or-power-off), which has a workaround, which I think is going to be the best solution for me, at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1427781/453639)

Comment: I have banged my head against this for many uncounted hours; I do believe this is the biggest pain I have ever encountered with any OS.  It really helps me appreciate Windows, which is too bad because otherwise I really like the FOSS vibe.  But with stupid problems like this, how can anyone seriously expect a business to adopt Linux desktop?  Come on Canonical, get it together!  I am *so* frustrated.