# The lock screen does not appear on the main screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, lock-screen

I have a dual screen on my computer and I have a small problem. When I am on my dual boot (Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10), Bios or Windows 10, everything is displayed on screen 1. However, when I log in on Linux, the lock screen is displayed on screen 2. Once I enter my password, everything is displayed on screen 1.

This is more of an annoying problem than a blocking one, but is there a way to switch the lock screen to screen 1 instead of 2 please? I would appreciate it.

PS: English is not my first language. I’m sorry if there are mistakes.

EDIT : Excellent! The answer given by @Cagri is still valid. Thank you very much! The topic can be considered solved.

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the display tab of the Settings app showing your settings of screen 1 and screen 2? Add the screenshot [to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1428699/edit).

Comment: does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04