# video and audio issues in Ubuntu 22.04 via external monitors

Tags: nvidia, sound, multiple-monitors, 22.04, dockstation

I have a quite tricky setup with which I faced all kinds of issues.

Setup:

- Laptop Dell Inspiron 16 7610 with NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU
- Dock station  Dell WD19TBS
- Screen 1: Huawei MateView HSN-CBA 28" 4k (with built-in sound system)
- Screen 2: Samsung U28E590D 4k

Issues I faced:

1. When display goes off then lock screen is always black and is not recovered.
2. After some time of work Huawei blinks, becomes black for a second, sound disappears from monitor
3. After connecting a second monitor one of them does not work
4. Login screen is on a build in monitor

Answer (score 0):

I spent total around 50 hours, because while fixing one, another was appearing.

I will describe step by step what I did to fix all of this and hope my knowledge will save some time for somebody else.

Note: we are rebooting after each step. I would strongly recommend to do it, otherwise some settings may clash.

1. Disabled Wayland

   - `sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
   - Set `WaylandEnable=false`
   - reboot
2. Update NVIDIA driver to `520.56.06`

   - You can find lots of tutorials how to do it
   - reboot
3. Modify grub

   - `sudo vim /etc/default/grub`
   - Update/append your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=off nouveau.modeset=0 nouveau.blacklist=1"`
   - `sudo update-grub`
   - reboot
4. Next, to solve issue when one of the screens is remained black and could not be turned on. But it might also affect the audio.

   Fix for me was to add a custom frequency for the Huawei screen.
   By default, it was only 60hz, but I think when you have two 4k monitors it might be that it is not enough bandwidth to pass such frequency.

   modify

   ```
    vim ~/.xprofile
   ```

   Set following content:

   ```
    #!/bin/sh
    xrandr --newmode "3840x2560_30.00"  406.50  3840 4112 4520 5200  2560 2563 2573 2606 -hsync +vsync
    xrandr --addmode DP-1-2 3840x2560_30.00
   ```

   > see [How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution)
5. Then

   - set Samsung screen to 1280x1024
   - disable built-in screen
   - set Huawei to the same low resolution. Idea is to set both screens to low resolution.
   - Apply changes
   - set Huawei to newly added resolution (3840x2560 30Hz).
   - Apply changes.
   - Then increase resolution for Samsung to 4k
   - Apply changes
6. Small issue that your login screen is still on built-in monitor

   ```
    sudo cp ~/.config/monitors.xml ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
    sudo chown gdm:gdm ~gdm/.config/monitors.xml
   ```

   > See [Is there to make the login screen appear on the external display in 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043337/is-there-to-make-the-login-screen-appear-on-the-external-display-in-18-04)
7. Finally, refresh your `pulseaudio`. (Install if not installed via `sudo apt install pulseaudio`)

   - `mv ~/.config/pulse ~/.config/old_pulse`
   - reboot

PS:
In case wiring also plays role. I connected both screens to the dock via DisplayPort cables. Huawei played really bad with HDMI. Dock station is connected to the laptop via Thunderbolt 4.
Power to the laptop is also supplied via Dock Station.

PPS: if still have the issue with black screen then try to remove nvidia services and reboot.

```
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl stop nvidia-resume.service

sudo systemctl disable nvidia-suspend.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-hibernate.service
sudo systemctl disable nvidia-resume.service

sudo rm /lib/systemd/system-sleep/nvidia
```